# Can the word "More" be used in this context

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, adverbs

We usually say:

> How far is London?

But suppose if I am along the way to London, and very tired.
Can I say:

> How more far is London?

I am not a native speaker.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are very tired, I would expect you to speak ungrammatically—most people do. So, I would not be surprised if you said something like that. In fact, this is the kind of sentence, composed of short words, that I'd say is common for somebody who is very tired to say. But that's different than asking if it's grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

The expression you are looking for is "how much further".

> How much further is London?

"More far" is not a phrase you will generally find in Standard English; the word ***further*** expresses the idea.

Comment: Can I use "how much farther is it to London," instead?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Both are natural and idiomatic.